# SwiftUI Navigation Stack - How to pass a navigation title to destination

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

Right now I'm learning NavigationStacks in SwiftUI and I'm wondering if there is a elegant solution for passing the title of the NavigationLink from the previous view.

Consider the following example:

```
struct Foo: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    let bar: [String]
}

let exampleData: [Foo] = [
    Foo(name: "Item 1", bar: ["Lorem", "ipsum"]),
    Foo(name: "Item 2", bar: ["Lorem2", "ipsum2"])
]

struct MyNavigationView: View {
    @State private var data = exampleData
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data) { d in
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    List{
                        ForEach(d.bar, id: \.self) { val in
                            Text(val)
                        }
                        
                    }.navigationTitle(d.name)
                }) {
                    Text(d.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created a NavigationStack and would like the destination to have `d.name` as its title:

```
struct MyNavigationStackView: View {
    @State private var data = exampleData
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(data) { d in
                NavigationLink(value: d.bar) {
                    Text(d.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Foo.self) { elements in
                // I cannot use Foo.self as a destination since it's already used for a different view
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: [String].self) { elements in
                List(elements, id: \.self) { e in
                    Text(e)
                } // <- I would like this list to have d.name as a navigationTitle like the NavigationView has
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some clever way to solve this without modifying my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can come by wrapping `Foo` into an auxiliary struct, let's call it `WrappedFoo`. When you pass the auxiliary struct, you unwrap it into the value of `Foo`, and read the properties one by one.

Like this...

This is the auxiliary struct:

```
struct WrappedFoo: Hashable {

    // It contains only one property of type Foo
    let foo: Foo
    
    init(_ foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List(data) { d in

            // Pass the auxiliary struct
            NavigationLink(value: WrappedFoo(d)) {
                Text(d.name)
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Foo.self) { elements in
            // I cannot use Foo.self as a destination since it's already used for a different view
        }

        // Use the auxiliary struct and get the value of the Foo property
        .navigationDestination(for: WrappedFoo.self) { wFoo in
            List(wFoo.foo.bar, id: \.self) { e in
                Text(e)
            }
            
            // "Unwrap" Foo to get the name
            .navigationTitle(wFoo.foo.name)
        }
    }
}
```